# How to get accuracy in RandomForest Model in Python?

Tags: python, linear-regression, random-forest

I got this script, that predict with RandomForest and LinearRegression the values for the seconds dataset.That works ok, the accuracy for the linear regression is 18% , too bad.

So Im trying with RandomForest, but I dont know how to calculate the accuracy of that model..

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import urllib
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV, LinearRegression, Lasso

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

data = pd.read_csv('EncuestaVieja.csv')
X = data[['Edad','Sexo','v1','v2','v3']]
y = data['Alumna']

dataP = pd.read_csv('EncuestaVieja_test.csv')
X_p = dataP[['Edad','Sexo','v1','v2','v3']]
y_p = dataP['Alumna']

dataT = pd.read_csv('EncuestaVieja_test_2.csv')
X_t = dataT[['Edad','Sexo','v1','v2','v3']]
y_t = dataT['Alumna']
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(X, y)

lr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50)
lr.fit(X, y)

X_test = pd.read_csv('EncuestaNueva.csv')[['Edad','Sexo','v1','v2','v3']]

predictions = regr.predict(X_test)


predictions2 = lr.predict(X_test)
print( 'RandomForest Accuracy: ')
print(((predictions2)))
print( '')
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_p,y_p)
accuracy = regressor.score(X_t,y_t)
print( 'Linear Regression Accuracy: ', accuracy*100,'%')
print(((predictions)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
RandomForest Accuracy: 
[ 1.64  2.54  2.6   2.38  1.64  1.32  1.68  2.56  3.    2.28  2.38  2.68
  2.9   2.5   2.78  1.96  1.56  2.6   2.12  2.76  2.74  1.66  1.68  2.12
  2.3   2.36  2.28  2.28  2.82  1.7   1.86  2.36  1.24]

Linear Regression Accuracy:  18.1336149086 %
[ 1.2681851   1.02802219  3.13377072  2.96885127  2.30808853  1.98814349
  2.39233726  2.8638321   1.86640316  2.63073399  2.21166731  2.25201016
  1.95065189  2.65360517  3.08855254  1.01229733  2.18225606  2.41802534
  2.43539473  2.50227407  1.71105799  1.88238089  2.12152321  3.33525397
  2.72820453  2.43241713  2.88757874  2.6242382   2.63087916  1.98379487
  2.25430306  1.96810279  0.8554685 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is handled with the score() method

```
lr.score(x_test, y_test)
```

This will return the R^2 value for your model. It looks like in your case you only have an x_test though.
Note that this is not the accuracy. Regression models do not use accuracy like classification models. Instead different metrics are computed such as, mean square error or coefficient of determination. These metrics can show how accurately predicted values match known values or how closely a regression model fits a regression line.

Comment: `R^2` is not accuracy.

Comment: @modesitt In regression problems you do not use "accuracy" . Usually accuracy is reserved for classification problems. For regression models you usually use other metrics like Mean Squared Error (MSE) or R^2 to show how close a model fits a regression line or how closely predicted values match known values.

Comment: I'm aware. It was more a hint to OP that they need to consider exactly what kind of metric they want. Also `R^2` is not `MSE` - it is normalized  `[-1,1]`.

Comment: I meant to put MSE or R^2. They indeed are not one in the same.

Comment: @MitchellLeefers how can I implement that in my code?

Comment: @JonTargaryen You should be able to just call the method with you model. So it would be lr.score(X_test). Of course if you want it to print the score you need to wrap that in a print statement like print(lr.score(X_test))

Comment: @MitchellLeefers it returns this `TypeError: score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`
remember I want to check the acuracy of dataP against dataT

Comment: @JonTargaryen Sorry for the slow response but, it almost sounds like you are trying to compare the accuracy of two different models? If that is the case then you would use dataP_score = score(X_p,y_p) and dataT_score = score(X_t, y_t)